# Split String by delimiter position using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, split, substring, delimiter

I have a string and I would like to split that string by delimiter at a certain position.

For example, my String is `F/P/O` and the result I am looking for is:

[image: Screenshot of desired result]

Therefore, I would like to separate the string by the furthest delimiter.
*Note: some of my strings are `F/O` also for which my SQL below works fine and returns desired result.*

The SQL I wrote is as follows:

```
SELECT Substr('F/P/O', 1, Instr('F/P/O', '/') - 1) part1, 
       Substr('F/P/O', Instr('F/P/O', '/') + 1)    part2 
FROM   dual
```

and the result is:

[image: Screenshot of unexpected result]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want to use `regexp_substr()` for this.  This should work for your example:

```
select regexp_substr(val, '[^/]+/[^/]+', 1, 1) as part1,
       regexp_substr(val, '[^/]+$', 1, 1) as part2
from (select 'F/P/O' as val from dual) t
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37569), by the way, is the SQL Fiddle.

Oops.  I missed the part of the question where it says the *last* delimiter.  For that, we can use `regex_replace()` for the first part:

```
select regexp_replace(val, '/[^/]+$', '', 1, 1) as part1,
       regexp_substr(val, '[^/]+$', 1, 1) as part2
from (select 'F/P/O' as val from dual) t
```

And [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37571) is this corresponding SQL Fiddle.

Comment: As soon as I made the comment about simpler (see below) I ran into a situation that was not simple. Thank you both Gordon Linoff, and Lalit Kumar B.

Answer (score 55):

> Therefore, I would like to separate the string by the furthest delimiter.

I know this is an old question, but this is a simple requirement for which **SUBSTR** and **INSTR** would suffice. **REGEXP** are still **slower** and **CPU intensive** operations than the old subtsr and instr functions.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 'F/P/O' str FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, Instr(str, '/', -1, 1) -1) part1,
  5         SUBSTR(str, Instr(str, '/', -1, 1) +1) part2
  6  FROM DATA
  7  /

PART1 PART2
----- -----
F/P   O
```

As you said you want the **furthest** delimiter, it would mean the first delimiter from the **reverse**.

You approach was fine, but you were missing the **start_position** in **INSTR**.  If the start_position is **negative**, the `INSTR` function counts back start_position number of characters from the end of string and then searches towards the beginning of string.

Comment: simple is better: substr and instr is simpler than 'regexp_substr'