# How to Split a comma separated string in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, substr

How to Split a comma separated string in Oracle using `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`.

**String '20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2'**.

I tried using the below code, but I'm unable get the value after the 2nd comma.

```
SELECT substr('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2',0,instr('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2',',')-1) 
value FROM dual   -- 1. 20.4
```

for second value i'm getting the entire string after 2nd comma.

```
SELECT substr('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2',instr('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2',',')+1,instr('20.4,
12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2',',',2,2)-1) st FROM dual   -- result : 12.5,3.5,
```

I want the value after each comma, like

20.4

12.5

3.5 and so on.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878291/split-string-by-delimiter-position-using-oracle-sql

Comment: I want it without using "REGEXP" function.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the regexp function?

Comment: I'm getting the result with regex. I'm trying whether its possible to get without regex.

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('20.4 12.5 3.5 0.2 0.2', '(\S*)(\s)', 1, 2)
FROM dual;   just have to change the position

Answer (score 11, accepted):

based on https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement :

First, we will form a query, that splits this comma separated string and gives the individual strings as rows.

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
     connect by regexp_substr('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;


REGEXP_SUBSTR('20.4,1
---------------------
20.4                 
12.5                 
3.5                  
0.2                  
0.2
```

The above query iterates through the comma separated string, searches for the comma (,) and then splits the string by treating the comma as delimiter. It returns the string as a row, whenever it hits a delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

> > You can also check for a specific occurrence, sample, ever second occurrence between comma.

```sql
SQL> select regexp_substr('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2','[^,]+[^,]', 1,2 ) as 2nd_occur 
     from dual;

 ", 1,2 )" -- You can replace this query part to choose with occurrence you want, like 

 ", 1,3 )" -- for third occurrence.`


Output:

2nd_occur
---------
12.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have APEX 5.1 or higher installed in the your database, you can solve this quite elegantly, using [apex_string.split](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.htm#AEAPI-GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6) :

```
select column_value
from table(apex_string.split('20.4,12.5,3.5,0.2,0.2', ','))
```