# Split comma separated values into rows with other columns on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have this data:

[image]

that needs to be converted into this:

[image]

I saw some samples about regexp_substr but I can't seem to make it work on my procedure.

```
   With folder_query as 
   (
       SELECT * FROM
       (SELECT ID, CardNo, REPLACE(LICENCE (RSN, 1), '<br/>', '') AS TagNo
         FROM FOLDER1) SQ
   )
   SELECT ID, CardNo,regexp_substr(TagNo,'[^,]+',1,level) AS TagNo
   FROM folder_query
   CONNECT by level <= REGEXP_COUNT(TagNo, '[^,]+')
```

I got some errors:

ORA-30563: outer join operator (+) is not allowed here
30563. 00000 -  "outer join operator (+) is not allowed here"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to reference (+) in either the select-list,
CONNECT BY clause, START WITH clause, or ORDER BY clause.
*Action:   Do not use the operator in the select-list, CONNECT BY clause,
START WITH clause, or ORDER BY clause.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times before. Did you search it? Here one example: [How to Split a comma separated string in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260177/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string-in-oracle)

Comment: I presented the error I got after I followed some of the samples I got online. Apparently, it's not working how it supposed to be. That's why I'm asking for some help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, for sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID     CARDNO TAGNO
---------- ---------- -----------------------
     84773  317012878 AA7 101 443,AA5 101 453    
     84774  317012878 AA2 101 493
```

Query:

```
SQL> select id, cardno,
  2    regexp_substr(tagno, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) tagno
  3  from test cross join
  4    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  5                        connect by level <= regexp_count(tagno, ',') + 1
  6                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

        ID     CARDNO TAGNO
---------- ---------- --------------------
     84773  317012878 AA7 101 443
     84773  317012878 AA5 101 453
     84774  317012878 AA2 101 493

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with rws as (
  select '84773' id, 'AA7 101 443,AA5 101 453'  tagno from dual UNION ALL 
  select '84774' id, 'AA2 101 493' tagno from dual 
),
rcte (id, tagno, cnt, lvl, value) as (
  select id, tagno, length ( tagno ) - length ( replace ( tagno, ',' ) ), 1,
       regexp_substr (
           tagno,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           1
         )
  from   rws
  union all
  select id, tagno, cnt, lvl + 1,
       regexp_substr (
           tagno,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           lvl + 1
         )
  from   rcte
  where  lvl <= cnt
)
select id, value
from rcte
order by id, value;


ID    VALUE
84773 AA5 101 453
84773 AA7 101 443
84774 AA2 101 493
```