# Need to separate last_name and domain from mail id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have sample mail-id like below:

```
raju.das@gmail.com
javed.khan@gmail.com
Amit.kumar.bera@yahoo.com
```

So, I need the output like below:

```
das   Gmail
Khan  gmail
bera  yahoo
```

Using `regexp` am able to do it, but It's not giving  correct output when mail id is coming with middle name. Can anyone please help me on it.

Comment: Regexp it's slow  you should consider something else to make something like that, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878291/split-string-by-delimiter-position-using-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple string functions `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` (which are much faster than regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(local_part, INSTR(local_part, '.', -1) + 1) AS last_name,
       SUBSTR(domain, 1, INSTR(domain, '.') - 1) AS domain
FROM   (
  SELECT SUBSTR(email, 1, INSTR(email, '@', -1) - 1) AS local_part,
         SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@', -1) + 1) AS domain
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(email) AS
SELECT 'raju.das@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'javed.khan@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Amit.kumar.bera@example.com' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LAST_NAME | DOMAIN |
| --- | --- |
| das | example |
| khan | example |
| bera | example |

If you did want to use regular expression (which will be slower) then:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '([^.]+)@([^.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS last_name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '([^.]+)@([^.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS domain
FROM   table_name;
```

Gives the same output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LRgIVmEk)